# populate array based on value banding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create an array of data based on the "age" of a person. This banding is not linear, but grouped something like

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11-15,16-20,21-30,31-50,51+

so for any set of data, I need to run through this and put the person into the appropriate age "bucket"

At the end of the loop, I want to see how many people are in each banding.

Now, I have done this by using very crude techniques (aka if this .. then .. else if .. ) ;), but was wondering if I could learn new techniques and if there was any library or function that could take a range and fill the bucket accordingly

Comment: do you have some test data?

Comment: I do, but it could be considered just a random set of numbers / ages .. 

let people = [{name: "john", age: 29} ... {name: "fred", age: 99} ]

Comment: Does it have to be a simple array?  An array of objects would hold this data much better . . .

Comment: for my purposes, yes. However, very open to a more generic solution. In the example data above, I would want bucket[12] to be 1, and bucket[14] to be 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what I would do:

```
let buckets = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11-15,16-20,21-30,31-50,51+'.split(','),
    bucketByAge = {}; // our bucket-age connector where we search later on

// prepare the index
buckets.forEach(function(bucket, index) {
  // get the range (+ will be replaced with 1000; for the age it is infinity)
  // and transform them to numbers
  let range = bucket.replace('+', '-1000').split('-').map(Number);

  // if it was not a range, simulate one
  range[1] = range[1] || range[0];

  // go through the range and fill our connector
  while (range[0] <= range[1]--) {
    bucketByAge[range[1]] = index;
  }
});

// search
function getBucket(age) {
  return { age: age, bucketRange: buckets[bucketByAge[age]], bucketIndex: bucketByAge[age] };
}

console.log(getBucket(1));
console.log(getBucket(12));
console.log(getBucket(61));
```

What's good here: you build the index once and later just take the result. Very performant.

Answer (score 0):

A VERY rough o(n^2) implementation

```js
const buckets = [
  {
    lowerLim: 1,
    upperLim: 1,
    persons: 0
  },
  {
    lowerLim: 2,
    upperLim: 2,
    persons: 0
  },
  {
    lowerLim: 3,
    upperLim: 5,
    persons: 0
  },
  {
    lowerLim: 6,
    upperLim: 10,
    persons: 0
  },
  {
    lowerLim: 11,
    persons: 0
  }
];


const persons = [{name: 'john', age: 1},{name: 'john', age: 2}, {name: 'john', age: 6}, {name: 'john', age: 20}, {name: 'john', age: 40}, {name: 'john', age: 7}, {name: 'john', age: 1}];

persons.forEach(person => {
  buckets.forEach(bucket => {
    const age = person.age;
    const bucketLowerLimit = bucket.lowerLim;
    const bucketUpperLimit = bucket.upperLim || Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    if(age >= bucketLowerLimit && age <= bucketUpperLimit) {
      bucket.persons++;
    }
  })
});


buckets.forEach(bucket => {
  console.log(bucket.persons);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reference for all values inbetween and a separate last value.

```js
var slots = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11-15,16-20,21-30,31-50,51+'.split(','),
    last = slots.pop(),
    reference = Object.create(null),
    histogram = Object.create(null),
    i, value;

slots.forEach(function (a) {
    var temp = a.split('-'),
        left = temp[0],
        right = temp[1] || temp[0];

    histogram[a] = 0;
    reference[right] = a;
    while (left < right) {
        reference[left] = a;
        left++;
    }
});

histogram[last] = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    histogram[reference[value] || last]++;
}

console.log(histogram);
console.log(reference);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```